# SlidingMenu (jfeinstein10) in Sherlock Activity error

Tags: android, view, actionbarsherlock, slidingmenu

I'm trying to add a sliding menu to my MainActivity. I imported SlidingMenu and ActionBarSherlock and tried to apply to my code. When I run my app in 4.2.2 tablet, my app looks good and works perfectly. But when I try to run it in virtual devices which are 4.1.1, 4.4.4 and 5.0.0, sliding action works but the view doesn't occur. Here is codes.

MainActivity(Simplified);

```
public class MainActivityMain extends SherlockActivity {
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    //SlidingMenu
    menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_shadow_width);
    menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.graytrans);
    menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
    menu.setMenu(getSlidingView());
    }

        //View of slidingMenu
    public View getSlidingView(){
    View view;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slidingmenulayout, null);
    ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listViewOfSlidingMenu);
    lv.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(this,monthNames));
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if(position == 12){
                title.setText(monthNames[position]);
                listView.setAdapter(new PersonAdapter(mContext, people));
                menu.toggle();
            }
            else{
            title.setText(monthNames[position]);
            listView.setAdapter(new PersonAdapter(mContext,    getThisMonthsPeople(people, position+1)));
            menu.toggle();
            }
        }
    });
    ImageButton close = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.backarrow);
    close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            menu.toggle();
        }
    });
    return view;
    }
}
```

How it looks in my tablet(4.2.2):
[image: How it looks in my tablet(4.2.2):]
How it looks in virtual device(5.0.0):
[image]

As you can see, in virtual device sliding menu is on right side. But it should be on left. And there is no view in it. What is your opinion according to this situation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You do know ActionBarSherlock has been deprecated by its author, right ?

Comment: I didnt know that. What is your suggestion? @2Dee

Comment: My suggestion would be the same as the one given by the creator of ABS : use AppCompat. Check this out : http://android-developers.blogspot.be/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html